# can't load angular.js for unit test with karma, jasmine, phantomjs, and maven

Tags: maven, angularjs, jasmine, phantomjs, karma-runner

I'm trying to arrange my alphabet soup of angular, karma, jasmine, phantomjs, and maven.  I'm doing this with a toy project for now, in preparation for integrating into a real project.

The following is my relevant list of files:

```
./pom.xml
./src/main/webapp/index.html
./src/main/webapp/js/blog.js
./src/test/webapp/js/blogSpec.js
./src/test/webapp/js/karma.conf.js
./src/test/webapp/js/libs/angular-mocks.js
./src/test/webapp/js/libs/angular.js
```

Here is my complete pom:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.att.cdits</groupId>
  <artifactId>angularjsexp</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>com.kelveden</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-karma-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.5</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>start</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
            <configFile>${basedir}/src/test/webapp/js/karma.conf.js</configFile>
            <browsers>PhantomJS</browsers>
            <reporters>dots</reporters>
            <colors>false</colors>
            <autoWatch>false</autoWatch>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.kelveden</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-karma-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.5</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

And my "karma.conf.js" file:

```
module.exports = function(config) {
  config.set({
    basePath: '',
    frameworks: ['jasmine'],
    files: [
      "../../../../src/test/webapp/js/libs/*.js",
      "../../../../src/main/webapp/js/*.js",
      "../../../../src/test/webapp/js/*.js"
    ],
    exclude: [],
    reporters: ['dots'],
    port: 9876,
    colors: false,
    logLevel: config.LOG_DEBUG,
    autoWatch: false,
    browsers: ['PhantomJS'],
    captureTimeout: 60000,
    singleRun: true
  });
};
```

The following is an excerpt from my "mvn install" output, starting at the Surefire execution:

```
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.10:test (default-test) @ angularjsexp ---
[INFO] Surefire report directory: myhome\workspace6\angularjsexp\target\surefire-reports

-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------

Results :

Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0

[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-karma-plugin:1.5:start (default) @ angularjsexp ---
cmd /C karma start myhome\workspace6\angularjsexp\src\test\webapp\js\karma.conf.js --browsers PhantomJS --reporters dots --single-run --no-auto-watch --colors false
DEBUG [plugin]: Loading karma-* from myhome\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules 
DEBUG [plugin]: Loading plugin myhome\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules/karma-chrome-launcher. 
DEBUG [plugin]: Loading plugin myhome\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules/karma-coffee-preprocessor. 
DEBUG [plugin]: Loading plugin myhome\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules/karma-firefox-launcher. 
DEBUG [plugin]: Loading plugin myhome\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules/karma-html2js-preprocessor. 
DEBUG [plugin]: Loading plugin myhome\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules/karma-jasmine. 
DEBUG [plugin]: Loading plugin myhome\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules/karma-phantomjs-launcher. 
DEBUG [plugin]: Loading plugin myhome\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules/karma-requirejs. 
DEBUG [plugin]: Loading plugin myhome\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules/karma-script-launcher. 
DEBUG [plugin]: Loading inlined plugin (defining ). 
INFO [karma]: Karma v0.10.2 server started at http://localhost:9876/ 
INFO [launcher]: Starting browser PhantomJS 
DEBUG [launcher]: Creating temp dir at C:\Cygwin\tmp\karma-77302282 
DEBUG [launcher]: myhome\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\karma-phantomjs-launcher\node_modules\phantomjs\lib\phantom\phantomjs.exe C:\Cygwin\tmp\karma-77302282/capture.js 
DEBUG [watcher]: Excluded file "myhome/workspace6/angularjsexp/src/test/webapp/js/karma.conf.js" 
DEBUG [watcher]: Resolved files: 
    myhome/AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/karma-jasmine/lib/jasmine.js 
    myhome/AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/karma-jasmine/lib/adapter.js 
    myhome/workspace6/angularjsexp/src/test/webapp/js/libs/angular-mocks.js 
    myhome/workspace6/angularjsexp/src/test/webapp/js/libs/angular.js 
    myhome/workspace6/angularjsexp/src/main/webapp/js/blog.js 
    myhome/workspace6/angularjsexp/src/main/webapp/js/checkbox-array.js 
    myhome/workspace6/angularjsexp/src/main/webapp/js/my-include.js 
    myhome/workspace6/angularjsexp/src/test/webapp/js/blogSpec.js 
DEBUG [web-server]: serving: myhome\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\karma\static/client.html 
DEBUG [web-server]: serving: myhome\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\karma\static/karma.js 
DEBUG [karma]: A browser has connected on socket LI1NDCsuY-0i0Uxwkhs_ 
INFO [PhantomJS 1.9.2 (Windows 7)]: Connected on socket LI1NDCsuY-0i0Uxwkhs_ 
DEBUG [karma]: All browsers are ready, executing 
DEBUG [web-server]: serving: myhome\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\karma\static/context.html 
DEBUG [web-server]: serving: myhome/AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/karma-jasmine/lib/adapter.js 
DEBUG [web-server]: serving: myhome/AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/karma-jasmine/lib/jasmine.js 
DEBUG [web-server]: serving: myhome/workspace6/angularjsexp/src/test/webapp/js/libs/angular.js 
DEBUG [web-server]: serving: myhome/workspace6/angularjsexp/src/main/webapp/js/checkbox-array.js 
DEBUG [web-server]: serving: myhome/workspace6/angularjsexp/src/main/webapp/js/blog.js 
DEBUG [web-server]: serving: myhome/workspace6/angularjsexp/src/main/webapp/js/my-include.js 
DEBUG [web-server]: serving: myhome/workspace6/angularjsexp/src/test/webapp/js/blogSpec.js 
DEBUG [web-server]: serving: myhome/workspace6/angularjsexp/src/test/webapp/js/libs/angular-mocks.js 
PhantomJS 1.9.2 (Windows 7) ERROR 
    ReferenceError: Can't find variable: angular 
    at myhome/workspace6/angularjsexp/src/test/webapp/js/libs/angular-mocks.js:16 
PhantomJS 1.9.2 (Windows 7) ERROR 
    ReferenceError: Can't find variable: myApp 
    at myhome/workspace6/angularjsexp/src/main/webapp/js/checkbox-array.js:1 
PhantomJS 1.9.2 (Windows 7) ERROR 
    ReferenceError: Can't find variable: myApp 
    at myhome/workspace6/angularjsexp/src/main/webapp/js/my-include.js:1 
PhantomJS 1.9.2 (Windows 7) ERROR 
    ReferenceError: Can't find variable: module 
    at myhome/workspace6/angularjsexp/src/test/webapp/js/blogSpec.js:5 
PhantomJS 1.9.2 (Windows 7): Executed 0 of 0 ERROR (0.273 secs / 0 secs)
```

I have the following issues so far, some annoyances, some blockers:
* It's weird that karma resolves file path references relative to where it found my conf file, I wish I could override that.
* It appears that Surefire fires before Karma.  Is it possible to integrate these?
* My references to "angular" and other objects in my scripts are obviously failing. I don't understand how to resolve this.

Answer (score 12):

Thanks to someone on the karma-users discussion group, I discovered that the files loaded from "files" have to be loaded in the correct order.  For instance, instead of "`../../../../src/test/webapp/js/libs/*.js`", I need to specify "`../../../../src/test/webapp/js/libs/angular.js`", then "`../../../../src/test/webapp/js/libs/angular-mocks.js`".

I still have to figure out how to properly integrate Surefire, but I'll ask that separately.

Answer (score 7):

I have been testing Angular with Karma and Jasmine and finally it works! My example is much simpler than yours, but maybe it can help you. I have an application in Angular in two files:

- `controllers.js`
- `application.js`

And the following files for Angular:

- `angular.js`
- `angular-mocks.js`
- `angular-route.js`

I have edited the `karma.config.js` manually and I have put files instead of routes because it works in a concrete order, so finally the ordered file list for Karma is:

```
// list of files / patterns to load in the browser
files: [
  'js/libs/angular.js',
  'js/libs/angular-mocks.js',
  'js/libs/angular-route.js',
  'js/controllers.js',
  'js/application.js',
  'spec/*.spec.js'
],

// list of files to exclude
exclude: [
  'karma.config.js'
],
```

My directory tree is:

- karma.config.js
- /js

  - application.js
  - controllers.js
  - /libs

    - angular.js
    - angular-mocks.js
    - angular-route.js
- /spec

  - application.spec.js

And I test Karma in the root folder with `$ karma start karma.config.js`.

Hope this helps